# Extend line with given points

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, line

I have a few lines plotted with points in a graph that look like the one in the image posted below:
let's say for example that I have the coordinates for points A & B, which I use to set the line. What I'd like to do is have the line go all the way from x=0 to x=100, adding the two missing "x" pieces.
[image]
I'm using `d3.svg.line()` to set the `.x` and `.y` accessor functions, and then a path to plot the line. Is there a function to add to the line or path generator that does what I'd like to obtain?
Any hint is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no built in way to do it, but it's not too hard to calculate yourself.

Let's say you're currently drawing the line between `A` and `B` like this:

```
var A = [15, 40], // x of 15 and y of 40
    B = [85, 90],
    line = d3.svg.line();

path.attr('d', line([A,B]))
```

You need to calculate `p0` and `p1` at x of 0 and 100, taking into account the slope of the line and a point that the line goes through. So you need a function `pointAtX()` that takes as params `A` and `B` and a desired x coordinate and returns the appropriate y coordinate.

```
function pointAtX(a, b, x) {
  var slope = (b[1] - a[1]) / (b[0] - a[0])
  var y = a[1] + (x - a[0]) * slope
  return [x, y]
}
```

Then you can draw the line like this:

```
var A = [15, 40], // x of 15 and y of 40
    B = [85, 90],
    line = d3.svg.line(),
    p0 = pointAtX(A, B, 0),
    p1 = pointAtX(A, B, 100),

path.attr('d', line([p0,p1]))
```

Interestingly, the implementation of `pointAtX()` can be re-written to make use of `d3.scale.linear`. Not sure it's better, but kind of cool:

```
var interpolator = d3.scale.linear()
function pointAtX(a, b, x) {
  interpolator
    .domain([a[0], b[0]])
    .range([a[1], b[1]]);
  return [x, interpolator(x)];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the linear scale idea. IMHO this is how you would want to do it.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff A neat thing about the scale approach is that it can work with other types of scales, such that the resulting curve always passes through points A and B. http://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/Lg7Md/1/